# Get the city by ip adrresse in php

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-5.4, php-5.5

I have a biig problem with get the city by ip addresse in php, the code work yersteday but now I got an error:
Limit Exceed,
my code:

```
 public function getCityAndCountryByIp($ip){
    //get the city
    $tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.geobytes.com/IpLocator.htm?GetLocation&template=php3.txt&IpAddress='.$ip);

    $result = $tags['city'];
    return $result;
```

Help me please, the code work earlier, Any suggestions please

Comment: So you have exceeded limit, that's why you can't use it any more.

Answer (score 2):

The error **Limit exceed** should be pretty clear that you used all the free requests for the given period. You should purchase a license for more requests, or use a free service.

Comment: Exist a solution, what free service?

Answer (score 0):

Use the php geoip extension it has a free and commercial version http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php

Comment: Follow those instructions to install it https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-php/blob/master/README.md